# Nature of the intersection in Van Kampen

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I am a little confused about how to understand the path connected intersection requirement of Van Kampen's Theorem.

Most examples I have seen for $S^1 \vee S^1$ take the following decomposition:

[image]

However, why not take the point of contact to be $U\cap V$ and $U,V$ to be the circles. $U\cap V$ would still be path connected, since it is a single point.

Am I correct and it just so happens that I haven't come across a point intersection example, or is there a reason why point intersection are not taken in applying the Van Kampen Theorem?

Comment: Seifert-Van Kampen requires $U$ and $V$ (and therefore $U\cap V$ as well) to be open.

Comment: Missed this bit, thanks @SassatelliGiulio! Could you please add it as an answer, so I can mark this as "accepted"

Comment: I'd rather somebody else do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the standard vesion of the Seifert - van Kampen theorem both $U,V$ are required to be open.

However, we easily get the following corollary:

Let  $(Z,*)  = (X_1,x_1) \vee (X_2,x_2)$ be the one-point union of the two based spaces $(X_i,x_i)$. If $\{x_i\}$ is a strong deformation retract of an open neighborhood $U_i \subset X_i$, then $\pi_1(Z,*) \approx \pi_1(X_1,x_1) * \pi_1(X_2,x_2)$.

This clearly applies to $S^1 \vee S^1$.

*Proof.* Let $V_1 = X_1 \vee U_2$ and $V_2 = U_1 \vee X_2$. These are open subsets of $Z$ which cover $Z$. The intersection $V_1 \cap V_2$ is contractible. Now apply Seifert - van Kampen, noting that $(V_i,*) \simeq (X_i,x_i)$.